# If I just include images 3 times as large for iOS, will it auto-resize?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, xcasset

I know if I just include `image@3x.png` in my Images.xcassets, that it'll be shrunk accordingly whenever I need it for 1x and 2x situations.

My users will all have profile pictures. I don't store them on the phone. Is it enough to store one of 3x size on the server and expect that when I select it as a UIImage, it'll be automatically shrunk as well?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be shrunk. What will happen is that your image from the server will be put in the space as it is. If you want my 2 cents on this, resize them on your server and download them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the contentMode ( UIViewContentMode) of the ImageView where yo present them:

```
ScaleToFill
ScaleAspectFit
ScaleAspectFill
```

Will schrink the image to fit the view. The others wont't.(Though I'm now not really sure what Redraw does)

From the docs: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode

```
Options to specify how a view adjusts its content when its size changes. 

Declaration
SWIFT
enum UIViewContentMode : Int {
case ScaleToFill
case ScaleAspectFit
case ScaleAspectFill
case Redraw
case Center
case Top
case Bottom
case Left
case Right
case TopLeft
case TopRight
case BottomLeft
case BottomRight
}
```

The @3x and @2x just tells you that the image should be used with a certain screen pixel density and it does not guarantee that it will fit anywhere.